# Style not being applied to Google Fusion Table Layer

Tags: javascript, json, google-fusion-tables

I have a method that queries one of the public Fusion tables of state boundaries.  What I'd like to do is highlight Wisconsin in a different color and change the fill level different for Illinois.  Here is the code:

```
 layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(531237, {
         query: "select geometry from 531237 WHERE STATE_ABBR in (" + states + ") " ,
         styles: [                       
                    { where: "STATE_ABBR = 'WI'", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#0000FF" } },
                    { where: "STATE_ABBR = 'IL'", polygonOptions: { fillOpacity: 1.0} }
                 ]
        });
layer.setMap(map);
```

When the query returns, Wisconsin and Illinois are still the same highlighted color as all the other states.  Is there something syntactically wrong with how I'm trying to style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something more like this:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query: {
     select: 'geometry',
     from: '531237',
     where: "STATE_ABBR in (" + states + ") "
   },
   styles: [                       
     { where: "STATE_ABBR = 'WI'", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#0000FF" } },
     { where: "STATE_ABBR = 'IL'", polygonOptions: { fillOpacity: 1.0} }
   ]
});
```